# Add iPad Storyboard to existing project

Tags: ipad, storyboard

i have a working and almost finished application for iphone and i want to make it working on ipad too. I use iphone storyboard.How to add iPad storyboard and link it with the code?

Answer (score 11):

I haven't done this before, but isn't the solution just to add a separate storyboard-file for your iPad interface? Choose file -> New -> File. Then in the iOS / User Interface section, click on storyboard and hit next. Make sure you choose iPad as Device Family.

In your iOS Application Target change Devices from iPhone to Universal. Scroll down and select your Storyboard file for your iPad in the iPad Deployment Info section.

The rest should be pretty much like making your iPhone app. You'll have to make the iPad UI and connect buttons, make icons, etc.